# See where HTML element get it stylesheet from

Tags: html, css, gridview, stylesheet

I have a project in Visual Studio 2010.
There's a master page, with a content page and a gridview on the content page.  And a css file linked to the master page.

Are there a way to see where my GridView get it's stylesheet from? 
It does not specify a style explicitly, and my css file does not have a GridView element, but yet it's getting a style.
I just would like to know what elements in my css files get applied to the GridView so I can change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FireBug for Mozilla has a CSS inspector which will resolve all cascading and tell you where the style came from.

Comment: Chrome also has element inspection through Developer Tools (F12)